# Using Zend_Form, should a submit button be part of the definition list?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hey guys, does it make sense to have a submit button within the definition list, as there isn't really a definition term for it?

Comment: which definition list? you do submit buttons like this. 

submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Rss Feed $submit->addValidator('NotEmpty');
$this->addElement($submit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as the DL thing is just a decorator scheme, it's kind of an arbitrary discussion.

Maybe something a little more concrete is whether to include your buttons in the same display group as the rest of the elements.

My usual scheme puts any buttons in their own display group (`form_buttons`).